# C# Check If Xampp Server/Localhost is Running

Tags: c#, php, xampp, localhost

I'm using PHP to develop a freight application but it has to be a WindowsForm application. Using visual C#, I'm displaying webpages using webBrowser and the files are on the local server. Xampp needs to start all services before my application runs so it read php,etc. This works well.
The problem is. If I don't run Xampp services the browser will show an error "Navigation to the webpage was canceled". The reason for this is obvious(no server running).
So what I would like to do in C# is check if the server is running or check if http://127.0.0.1/site is available. If it is not then display an error messgaeBox and if it is available, do nothing else.
[image: Message when Xampp is not running]

But I don't want the employees to see this message so If xampp services aren't running or localhost is not accessible I want to show a message box instead of attempting to load the page.
[image: Xampp Running with No Internet Connection. Works fine]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you have a message that says NO XAMPP in the background, how are you detecting that already? Nevermind, I think I understand now.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to say. This is text I typed in paint after pasting the screenshot. "No XAMPP" and "XAMPP Running" is not in the program.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to craft a web request in .Net and read the response code, use conditional logic to then choose your action.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://127.0.0.1/site");
// If required by the server, set the credentials.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
// Get the response.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) {
   // show messagebox here
}
```

Documentation that is pertinent [WebRequest Class Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

My code is untested but it should do what you need.

Comment: So many errors. Exactly how do I go about using the WebRequest class and HttpWebResponse?

Comment: Hey. After mixing your code with another I got it to work! Thanks. I'll mark that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

With help from Daniel Lane I got it to work.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/site");
            try
            {
                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    //Load Webpage
                }
            }
            catch (WebException erf)
            {
                using (WebResponse response = erf.Response)
                {
                    var errorForm = new error();
                    errorForm.Show();
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
```

From "WebRequest..." is in an event(load).

**Here are the results:**
[image: XAMPP Running So Form Opens]

---

[image: XAMPP Not Running So Error Form is shown instead of Form]

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpWebRequest to try to pull some page from your website and if successful you can also check the StatusCode on the HttpWebResponse. Should be 200 or similar.