# Detect if localhost/Xampp/Laragon is running

Tags: php, xampp, localserver

I am building a project where an online php script needs to loads files from the local server (this is not a public website).

Is it possible to detect if the local server is running or not and display a message. Something like this ([C# Check If Xampp Server/Localhost is Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421660/c-sharp-check-if-xampp-server-localhost-is-running)) but with php.

gethostbyname will not work.

```
$domain = '127.0.0.1/info.php'; // or $domain = 'localhost/info.php';
if (gethostbyname($domain) != $domain ) {
    echo 'Up and running';}
else {
    echo 'Run xampp first';
}
```

This will not work too

```
$file = '127.0.0.1/info.php';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    echo 'Run xampp first';
}
else {
    echo 'Up and running';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a URL, it's a local filename:

```
$file = '127.0.0.1/info.php';
```

It lacks the leading protocol specifier, so it's looking for a file named `info.php` in a directory named `127.0.0.1`.

You will need:

```
$file = 'http://127.0.0.1/info.php';
```

Then, assuming that `http://127.0.0.1/info.php` is a valid URL that will be served if the web service is running, you can use `file_get_contents()` to try and load the page. This will issue a warning and return false on failure.

```
if (@file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/info.php')) {
    echo "server is up";
} else {
    echo "server is down";
}
```

You could also use `get_headers()` as in your exmaple, but note that if you get a `404 Not Found`, that still means the server is up and running.

Comment: No luck, I get server is down even when local server is running. The file exist in place if i hit in the url http://127.0.0.1/info.php i get the page with the php info.

Comment: Run `var_dump(file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/info.php'));` to see what you get back.

Comment: I get Warning: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

Comment: Well there's your problem, just set `allow_url_fopen=1` in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: I activated allow_url_fopen=On and your script will work if i point to an online file but for localhost i get (Warning: file_get_contents(http://127.0.0.1/info.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in) i know it exists and hitting the url will load it. Where you able to check this in your localhost?